# Return a value of the active element in the doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

i am having a method implemented in which i have as arguments a doubly linked list and the data each node has. i want to return a value of the active element in the list.

My code is:

```
void DLCopy (tDLList *L, int *val)  {

tDLElemPtr pointer=NULL;
    if(L->Act!=NULL)
    {
        pointer=(tDLElemPtr) malloc(sizeof(struct tDLElem));
        if (pointer == NULL)
        {
            pointer->data=val;
            pointer->rptr = L->Act->rptr;
            pointer->lptr = L->Act;
            L->Act->rptr = pointer;
            L->Act->lptr = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            DLError();
        }
    }

}
```

any ideas??

it gives me return value = -2 no matter what.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `if (pointer == NULL)
        {
            pointer->data=val;` ???

Comment: `if(pointer == NULL)` --> `if(pointer != NULL)`

Comment: What is this code *trying* to do (besides not work). If all you're doing is fetching the active element node's value, nearly all of this code is unnecessary, and *definitely* the `malloc` isn't required.

Comment: nope..still the same result

Comment: well this is exactly what i am trying to do. return the value from the list active node

Comment: I think as how to create a link is funny but it can not be determined only this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying is to get the active element's value it just seems to be simply:

```
void DLCopy (tDLList *L, int *val)  
{
   if (L != NULL && L->Act != NULL && val != NULL) 
   {
      *val = L->Act->data;
   }
   else if (val != NULL)
   {
       *val = 1234;  // Default value if no active element (if desired)
   }
}
```

Note: `DLCopy()` is not a good name for this function.